# Nodejs mongoose sub sub document search

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, nodejs-server

I have schema like

```
const propertiesSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    shortDescription: String,
    totalArea: String,
    address: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Address",
        required: true
    }
})
```

and the address schema like this

```
const addressSchema = new Schema({
    addressLine1: {
        type:String,
        required:false
    },
    addressLine2: {
        type:String,
        required:false
    },
    city:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref:"City"
    }
})
```

and i want to search city from propertiesSchema am using mongoose for the mongodb. and also i have optional searchData object like

```
searchData = {
    "name":"test"
    "city":"5c8f7f178dec7c20f4783c0d"
}
```

here  the city id may be null and i need if the city id not null then only need to search city on propertiesSchema . please help to solve this problem. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

As `city` is an nested object you can query that like

`"address.city"`

```
Eg: 

searchData = {
    "name":"test"
    "address.city":"5c8f7f178dec7c20f4783c0d"
}
```

**UPDATE**

`'5c8f7f178dec7c20f4783c0d'` is a string. You should use

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c8f7f178dec7c20f4783c0d');
```

Comment: but i get the error when i trying this  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ city: '5c8f7f178dec7c20f4783c0d' }" at path "address" for model "Properties"

Comment: but even now its return the empty array not returning the filtered array